# Input text change whenever component variable values change jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

When elements A, B, or C change, they change the properties of `filename.a`, `filename.b`, etc.

But the input value is only assigned once. Is there a way to have the input text value change whenever the variables that make it up change?

Or must I update the text inside of every `change` function. I would have to violate DRY and put something like this inside `$("#filename").val(filename.a + " " + filename.b + " " + filename.c);`.

The following doesn't work because the input text is not "bound" to the variables, it is simply assigned once.

```
<input type="text" id="filename" />
<script>
$("#elementA").on("change",function() {
  filename.a = $(this).text();
});
$("#elementB").on("change",function() {
  filename.b = $(this).text();
});
$("#elementC").on("change",function() {
  filename.c = $(this).text();
});
$("#filename").val(filename.a + " " + filename.b + " " + filename.c);
</script>
```

Comment: Set the value i.e.`$("#filename").val(...);` in the `change` event handler

Comment: I have 3 event handlers. My problem is that I would have to put that into 3 or more event handlers and change it in 3 places. Is there some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give all `elements` a class and thus have one event listener to all changes/keyup from that class elements.

Then you can choose if you want the filename to be populated as you are typing keystorkes (i.e: `keyup()`) or after you have left the textbox (i.e: `.change() ).

In my snippet below, I preferred `.keyup()` since it makes more sense in theis context.

```js
$('.elements').keyup(function(){

   // if you want, you may use [ $().change() ] instead of [ $().keyup() ]

   var a = $('#elementA').val();
   var b = $('#elementB').val();
   var c = $('#elementC').val();
   
   $('#filename').val(a + ' '  + b  + ' ' + c);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="elements" id="elementA" placeholder="elementA"><br>
<input type="text" class="elements" id="elementB" placeholder="elementB"><br>
<input type="text" class="elements" id="elementC" placeholder="elementC">

<hr>
<h3>Result</h3>
<input type="text" id="filename" placeholder="filename" readonly=readonly>
```

Comment: Whether grouping selectors like this `$('#elementA,#elementB,#elementC')` or with a class `$('.elements')`, your answer is the simplest and easiest to read. I ended up adding a class. But don't you think it's better to use `$('.elements').on("keyup"` rather than `$('.elements').keyup`? In my case, I think I absolutely *have* to, because the target elements are dynamically added and removed from the page.

Comment: If they elements are dynamically added, then use `$(document).on('keyup','.elements',function(){ /* your code here */ });` and that should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

try below code

```
<script>
  function assignValue(){
      $("#filename").val($("#elementA").text() + " " + $("#elementB").text() + " " + $("#elementC").text());
  }


  $(function(){
    $('#elementA, #elementB, #elementC').on('change', function(){
      assignValue();
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I like the succintness of this code, I was actually thinking along these lines too.. then in assignValue(), if he has more filenames to add, he could push to an array, and could create a for loop that would iterate through that array.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#elementA, #elementB, #elementC").on("change",function() {

  var val = $(this).text();

  if($(this).is("#elementA"))
    filename.a = val;
  else if($(this).is("#elementB"))
    filename.b = val;
  else if($(this).is("#elementC"))
    filename.c = val;
    
  $("#filename").val(filename.a + " " + filename.b + " " + filename.c);
    
});
```

You can have just one event handler on all the inputs and change the value of filename object based on the input changed.

Then update the value of `#filename` inside the change event handler only.

#### Update:

One more thing you can do is you can calculate the name of the property dynamically.

```
$("#elementA, #elementB, #elementC").on("change",function() {

  var val = $(this).text();

  var id = this.id; // Will have 'elementA'
  var prop = id.replace("element", "").toLowerCase(); // Will have 'a'

  filename[prop] = val;

  $("#filename").val(filename.a + " " + filename.b + " " + filename.c);

});
```

Comment: Do I need to check what `$(this)` is or can I just do: `filename.a = $("#elementA").text(); filename.b = $("#elementB").text();` etc?

Comment: i.e. I would be updating all 3 object properties every time any of the selectors changed.

Comment: @ButtleButkus you can do that but in that case, you would unnecessarily overwriting 2 property value.

Comment: I don't think overwriting property values is very high resource usage is it? Your update is interesting, but unfortunately `elementA` etc, were just for the question. In reality, they have very different names.

Comment: @ButtleButkus oh okay. Yea they arent. You can do that :)